# Absolute convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nb_n$ if $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n^2$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n^2$ converge

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $(b_n)$ and $(a_n)$ sequences of real numbers. If $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n^2$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n^2$ converge, prove that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nb_n$ converges absolutely.

I would like to have a feedback on my proof and know if everything is correct, please.

*Proof.*

As $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n^2$ converges, $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n^2=0$. Therefore, $b_n^2$ is bounded and we have that: $\exists M>0$: $|b_n|<\sqrt{M}\ \forall n\in\mathbf{N}$ .

By analogous reasoning we obtain that $\forall \epsilon>0\ \exists N \ \forall n\ge N'$: $|a_n|<\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{M}(n-N)}$.

Let's show that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_nb_n|$ is Cauchy. By definition we have to show the following: $\forall \epsilon>0 \ \exists N' \ \forall n\ge N'$:

$|\sum_{k=N'}^{n}|a_kb_k||<\epsilon$

But,

$|\sum_{k=N'}^{n}|a_kb_k||=\sum_{k=N'}^{n}|a_kb_k|=\sum_{k=N''}^{n}|a_k||b_k|\le \sqrt{M}\sum_{k=N'}^{n}|a_n|\le \sqrt{M}\cdot \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{M}(n-N)}\cdot (n-N')$

If we set $N'=N$, we obtain that

$|\sum_{k=N'}^{n}|a_kb_k||\le \epsilon$. We conclude then that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nb_n$ converges absolutely.

Comment: Before looking at your proof: are you aware of the "standard" methods to tackle this problem, relying on either Cauchy-Schwarz or the AM-GM inequality?

Comment: @Clement C. I saw the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but the tthing is that i don't really want to apply it because we didn't proof it in class (Analysis I). So i would like to proof this type of things using the "basic" knowledge that I have without using something new. (Same for AM-GM)

Comment: Fair enough. (The AM-GM inequality can be seen as elementary, as it's equivalent to $(a-b)^2 \geq 0$; but in any case, it's worth having various proof techniques.)

Comment: @Clement C. Yes, of course, I'm 100% agree with you. Using other methods more interesting as well. Thank you !

Comment: The result you got by analogous reasoning is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof *cannot* be correct, as in the end you only used that (i) $(b_n)_n$ was bounded, and (ii) $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n =0$. But those those assumptions alone cannot imply convergence (let alone absolute convergence) of $\sum_n a_n b_n$, as otherwise we would get convergence of $\sum_n \frac{1}{n}\cdot 1$.

Now, **why** is it false? Well, you write

> By analogous reasoning we obtain that $\forall \epsilon>0\ \exists N \ \forall n\ge N$: $|a_n|<\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{M}(n-N)}$.

This step, for instance, is not true. It may holds for fixed $N,M$ (with a fixed $n$ on the RHS), but how do you prove it holds for **all** $n\geq N$? Here is a counterexample:
$$
a_n = \frac{1}{n^{2/3}}
$$
Note that $\sum_n a_n^2 < \infty$, but the statement you wrote does not hold.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation

Comment: @Daniil You're welcome! Glad this helped.

Comment: But if i set the following: $|a_n|<\frac{\sqrt{\epsilon}}{\sqrt{M}(n-N)}$ it still can't hold $\forall n\ge N$? As $|a_n^2|<\epsilon$ $\forall \epsilon>0$

Comment: Check with the specific example I gave you -- it won't. You are basically asking (for a bit more than) that $\lim_{n\to\infty} n a_n = 0$ there. @Daniil

Comment: My question might be very stupid, but I don’t really understand why it doesn’t hold ... the inequality tells me the inverse... applying your counter example I see clearly that it doesn’t hold, but looking only at the inequality I don’t understand why. As we have that $|a_n|^2<\epsilon \iff |a_n|<\sqrt{\epsilon}$. And we have as well that $|a_n|^2<\epsilon/M(n-N)^2<\epsilon \ \forall \epsilon>0$. Where does it fail?

Comment: @Danill Can you justify that last step? *Why* do "we have as well that"?

Comment: As the inequality holds $\forall \epsilon>0$ we can modify it how we want if it stays $>0$ no? If you could point where is my problem (if you see it), I would like to have an advice to see where I have lacunes, please.

Comment: Not quite: here, the RHS would depend on $n$. In "for all $\varepsilon$, there exists $N$ such that for all $n$, the $\varepsilon$ does not change with $n$. @Danill

Comment: @Danill Exactly. Basically, you can see that the inequality you claim is equivalent to $|(n-N)a_n | \leq \sqrt{\varepsilon/M}$, so this would be a statement involving the sequence $(n a_n)_n$ (more or less, ignoring the $N$)

Comment: I think I see now. Thank you very much for bearing me x) Moreover the beginning of your explanation (that proof can’t hold) is really nice. It made me look at this such of proofs differently)

Comment: @Daniil You're welcome! (Those types of "sanity checks" were unfortunately not very frequent during my studies... I find them very helpful, since it's hard sometimes to know if things are wrong for small and fixable technical reasons, or if there is a major conceptual roadblock)